# Making magic into a science in a science fantasy setting?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, balancing-magic-systems

Lately I've been thinking a lot about science fantasy settings, specifically the inclusion of magic within it. It feels most fitting for, in a society where technology is highly advanced and magic is present as well, it would make the most sense for magic to either be its own division of science, or somehow intertwined with disciplines of science. However, I haven't been entirely certain how to go about it.

My initial thought was adding another fundamental particle, to be specific, an uncharged, non spinning particle, a "neutral quark," which in its natural state only interacts with gravity, not through weak interaction or the other two fundamental interactions. The idea is essentially that it's stable and does not readily interact with other fundamental particles. However, it can be instigated into having a charge or spin which is how magic can occur. These neutral particles suddenly can be spurred into a different state in which they can act like quarks, electrons, or other particles, assembling to give the desired effect, be it enhancing speed or strength through artificially producing more ATP within cells. There would furthermore be another form of energy, "neutral energy", in which it could additionally be spurred to manifest itself as a given form of energy, be it thermal, kinetic, or any of the other basic forms of energy. This for instance could be used to "launch" a summoned fireball.

Is this, at the very least, semi logical or scientific? Particle physics is certainly not my expertise, but I wonder if it at the very least shows promise to develop further. One issue I'd be stuck on is how these particles and energies are accessed and made tangible-- perhaps that could be the "magical"/unknown aspect of it? Or how they decay back to that neutral state (if ever)

Or am I thinking too much into it? I'm blanking on whether or not there's a way to make a magic system that doesn't come down to "it just kinda does that" or "*overly pseudo-scientific system that modifies the universe to get it to work.*" Any input, or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to integrate magic at the standard-model level of fundamental particles is not only overkill, as most people don't even know what it is, but also almost impossible. If you are developing magical systems, I would recommend discussing energies rather than particles, as exemplified in, for example, The Dresden Files, the books at least.

Comment: @SamKitsune Yeah, this question has definitely helped me to realize that. Energies seem much easier to work around, along with simply being much more flexible in terms of what they could do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I integrate science and magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/163553/how-can-i-integrate-science-and-magic)  Additionally, if you [search the Stack for magic and science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+magic+science), you'll discover that this question has been asked multiple times in multiple ways. Frankly, you're asking the wrong question. Of course magic can be a science in your world - but you should start with defining your magic system, then we can work on integrating it.

Comment: BTW, if you want an interesting place to start, consider [Dark Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) and [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy). Today, they're mathematical bandaids that help us explain observed effects that our models don't predict. We don't know yet if it's the models that are wrong or the matter/energy that exists. But they're a great starting point for building the science of magic in your world. Let's say that Dark Energy solves astronomical problems just as we say... and it just so happens that it's also the source of your magic.

Comment: @SCPirate No problem! =(^-^)= ...While developing your magic system, feel free to discuss it up here, I'm eager to hear more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is Technobabble

Whether adhering to [Clarke's Third Law](https://slideplayer.com/9974434/32/images/slide_1.jpg) or not, magic is magic.  It achieves inexplicable results.  Everything you've said here is entirely at odds with everything we know about quarks, and physics in general.  Which is *fine*... but don't expect people to swallow it wholesale.  If Crichton had said, in *Jurassic Park*, that scientists had found a way to make DNA spontaneously assemble into whole dinosaurs, most people probably wouldn't read past that point.

You're postulating a subatomic particle that doesn't fit into any standard model, which can apparently at will change its intrinsic properties and have macro effects that are controllable by some interface with intelligent creatures.

**My assertion is that your big problem here is calling it a "quark".**  We know what quarks do, the configurations that make up various hadrons, and there's not really any space for this Swiss Army Quark in the model.

My suggestion would be to postulate something akin to but entirely separate from a photon, as Terry Pratchett did with the [thaum](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Thaum):

> The thaum is the basic unit of magic. Enthusiastic students together with Ponder Stibbons  have found out that the thaum is made up of so called resons, which are themselves made up of at least five flavours (including up, down, sideways, sex appeal and peppermint.

It's quantizable, you can argue that as a particle/wave duality, it can be energy or matter (not how that works, but much easier to handwave), and can readily be contrived as to weakly interact with other universal material until someone who knows what it is manipulates it.

If you wanted to be *particularly* handwavey, you could even suggest that the thaum manifests in a form that interacts more strongly with the physical world due to the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).  Left to its own devices, the thaum whizzes through matter like a neutrino, but if an intelligent observer thinks about its interaction in just the right way, they can force it into a state that strongly interacts or behaves as a different particle, per your original suggestion.

Comment: Addendum - the first wizard was someone who postulated that such a particle must exist, and in so doing accidentally manifested it.

Comment: Oh yeah, it 100% is technobabble/realistically absolutely nonsense, I thought I mentioned that in the post, but I might've accidentally left it out.

Comment: Ack, accidentally hit enter.
So you suggest making a particle similar to base particles that only acts in major forms when manipulated to do so? The idea at the end with the observer seems particularly interesting, leaning into the seeming randomness of magic while still giving a pseudo-logical/scientific reason to it. The thought of thaum "bullying" other particles into doing something different, leading to magic.

Comment: If magic is truly random, it isn't particularly useful, or likely even perceptible.  So there has to be a means of manipulating it, whether by intelligent observers or otherwise.  Heinlein's final work included a magical-esque system where psychics could use the observer effect to create a fountain of [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) used in a "quantum ramjet".  This would presumably be similar, and would also go a distance towards explaining why destructive effects are easier, as they require less precision.

Comment: I suppose random wasn't the right word. Perhaps inexplicability would be a better term? What I meant was how it simply seems to go from doing nothing to doing something. The observer effect gives an explanation (albeit a handwavey one, which I'm completely content with) of why it does that.