# Where does mana come from?

Tags: science-based, magic, energy

I’m slowly developing a magic system loosely based on how magic is usually seen to appear in most fantasies, but with consistent rules. So far I’ve decided that mana exists in the world alongside energy, and is used by mages to create/destroy/manipulate energy. Mages are known to go into critical condition and/or exhaustion when their mana is depleted, so I figured mana should be required for the body’s basic natural processes in addition to caloric energy, and that mana should be stored in blood.

The part I’m trying to figure out is how mages regain mana over time. Is mana a product of digestion like energy? Is it absorbed into the body from ambient mana in nature? And beyond that, where should mana come from in the first place? On Earth, energy arrives to the planet from the sun, plants use that energy, and animals obtain it from eating plants and each other. Should mana be the same way, or should it just be an ambient resource in the air that mages absorb and return to the environment when they cast magic?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Don't forget to take the [tour] or see the [help] if you have questions. I'm voting to close for now. As far as I can see we can't help you the way it's currently formulated. The best answer how mana would work would be an opinion, which makes it difficult to make a truly good answer. If you can make it so the answer isn't an opinion I'm happy to help. That might be impossible with an imagined substance though.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions about mana in your world, we have a strict limit for one questions per post. Each of the questions your are asking are entirely up to you. If you want mana to work a particular way in your world you can decide to have mana work that way. If not it won't. While we're here to help you build your fictional world we're not here to make decisions about your world for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "should"? Normally, this word implies compliance with some sort of ethical or moral code, or with some technical specification. It is quite difficult to see how the source of a fantasy resource could be or not be in compliance with such a code or specification.

Answer (score 1):

**Autotrophs and heterotrophs.**

https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/heterotrophs/

> Organisms are characterized into two broad categories based upon how
> they obtain their energy and nutrients: autotrophs and heterotrophs.
> Autotrophs are known as producers because they are able to make their
> own food from raw materials and energy. Examples include plants,
> algae, and some types of bacteria. Heterotrophs are known as consumers
> because they consume producers or other consumers. Dogs, birds, fish,
> and humans are all examples of heterotrophs.

You could use the same general scheme for mana.  Autotrophs obtain raw mana from naturally occurring sources.  Heterotrophs take mana accumulated by autotrophs or other heterotrophs.

Sometimes autotrophs feed heterotrophs.  Fruit is an example.  Calories are provided by the autotroph to the heterotroph in exchange for a service (i.e. the pooping out of seeds at a different location).  Some heterotrophs scavenge energy from dead matter - decomposerts.  Some heterotrophs eat other organisms.

You can work within this schema and it can be a guide to plausibility.  Most of the autotrophs we are familiar with get raw energy from the sun, but there are other sources for autotrophs, like chemical energy from [hydrothermal vents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent).  That would be a good parallel for mana - a main source but then some other sources that turn up later in the story.

Usually creatures of a type will all get energy in the same way.  You could make your wizards get their mana according to their school or branch of magic.  Autotrophic wizards get power direct from the source.  Heterotrophic scavenge power from natural accumulators, or animals, or even other wizards.  These interactions could be adversarial or could provide mutual benefit to both parties.

Thus they can all be characters but their methods will differ and their interactions too.

Comment: The question asks what the source of manna *should* be, not what it *could* be. Those are quite different questions.

Comment: @AlexP:  It *should* be something / with consistent rules. / as requested in the OP. 
 Since the OP made analogy in several places to energetics I thought those rules could apply here too.

Answer (score 1):

[First, I've written an answer on a similar question before. That said,](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161700/how-do-i-create-a-magic-particle-to-make-magic-work-with-physics/161775#161775)

Building a coherent "scientifically grounded" magic system is... tricky, but doable. In this specific scenario, I'd reccomend that you **change mana away from being an energy source to an energy transfer and conversion system.**

In effect, your mages would always be saturated with mana particles, but when they cast magic, these particles grab energy from their bodies and convert it or use it somehow to "cast magic". In this case, the actual energy source fueling the magic would be the spellcaster's innate biological energy which can come in multiple forms:

- ATP: This is the stuff that cells run off of and very high in energy density but also not suited for long-term storage. Casting via this source would allow the mage to channel a lot of energy quickly, but once their ATP stores are gone, they'd be exhausted and need to wait for their body to build more similar to how a short-distance sprinter feels after a run. A skilled mage knows how to cast spells that consume less power than their body's natural digestion and ATP-synthesis rate similar to how endurance runners can pace their energy expenditure. Essentially, the mages would be burning calories from what they eat or their biological fat stores.
- Thermal energy: In desperate times, a magic user can also transfer the thermal energy from their bodies into casting the spell: A human has around 4,200 Joules per kilo per degree of mass in thermal energy, so if a 70kg mage is willing to lower their entire body's temperature by a single degree, they could fuel a spell with 294 kJ of energy or about 16 times the power of a .50 BMG shot. Unfortunately though, lowering the core temperature of the body, especially the brain, can easily be fatal, so mages would need to be extremely careful when using this method.

**Implications and expansion opportunities of such a system:**

- Maybe every mage's mana saturation level isn't the same--some are naturally gifted with a higher saturation so they can channel the same amount of bodily energy into a more powerful spell.
- Mages would basically run on food, which has all sorts of implications. For example, the easiest way to keep a mage prisoner would be to feed them just enough that they don't die, but not enough so that they can use the excess energy to escape.
- The most powerful mages would resemble top-athletes from today: ultra-fit and ultra buff, they'd be figures like Phelps who consume tens of thousands of Calories per day to perform impressive feats of spellcasting. Alternatively, magic casters who only need a little power but over a long period of time could be really fat and use their built up fat stores to fuel spells.